# Javascript Div Population

Tags: javascript, html

I have two DIV elements on a webpage. I want to remove inner html of DIV B, if inner HTML of DIV A is added via a third party script which is not under my control.

What is the best way to achieve that in JS?

Comment: please elaborate your question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>You could just remove inner html of `DIV id=b` when you apply inner HTML to `DIV id=a`?</del>

Or if that's not possible, you could track the innerHTML of `DIV id=a` with a timer and see when it gets populated:

```
window.onload = function(){
var a = document.getElementById("a"),
    b = document.getElementById("b"),
    c = setInterval( function(){

        if( a.innerHTML && a.innerHTML.length > 0 ) {
        b.innerHTML = "";
        clearInterval(c);
        }

    }, 50 );
};
```

Note that the html structure must be like this:

`<div id="a"></div>`

I.E. no whitespace.